# Issue with mocked data in the inner describe (jasmine )

Tags: angular, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm learning to write test cases ,where in I have written an inner describe and mocked the data as well as in the code given below

```
describe('Bcomponent', () => {
  let component: BComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BComponent>;
 

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BComponent],
      providers: [PlainTextPipe, DataService]
    })
      .compileComponents();  //need this if using systemjs for inline styles and tempelate urls
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.pageData = { 'configData': { 'image': 'Hello' } };  //mock data
    spyOn(component, 'rPage');
    superNgOnInit = spyOn(BComponent.prototype, 'ngOnInit');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
   //Some other test cases here
  // ==============================================================================
  describe('setupPage', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component['pageData'] = { 'configData': { 'image': 'innerHello' } };  //mock data

      spyOn(component, 'rPage').and.callThrough();
      spyOn<any>(component, 'checkMode');
    });

    it('should check if  setupPage is called', () => {
      const sData = spyOn<any>(component, 'setupPage');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      //@ts-ignore
      expect(component.setPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
});
```

now inspite of the data being mocked ,when I run the above test cases I get "Cannot read property 'configData' of undefined" and the particular test case fails for the inner describe ,while all the test cases in the outer describe pass without any issue, where would i be going wrong in this and in the html part I have

```
<div id="sec">
   <app-im [imgData]="pageData['configData']['image']"></app-im>
</div>
```

any help or guidance in right direction would be helpful, as I'm still learning to write test cases using jasmine

Comment: I would strongly recommend **not** spying on the thing you're supposed to be testing, or interfering directly with its properties. Beyond that it's hard to say what the issue is without a [mre] including the component.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe. These test just look weird to me. Why are you recreating the fixture and component in the inner beforeEach?

Comment: @AndrewAlderson can you please then guide with a way to call a method ,i wrote inner describe coz  to check if the inner method inside a function is called or not to check that we need to execute the method mocking wont help

Comment: @jonrsharpe plz if you can elaborate?

Comment: Not without the example, please [edit] to provide one (as recommended in [ask]). I'd also suggest reading Angular's [guidance on testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing), which covers a lot of cases and largely uses good practices.

Comment: @Swarup: Try going through my article. https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 . It has few articles associated in the bottom. I am sure it'll help you in understanding the test in Angular

Comment: @ShashankVivek sure will go through it ,thanks.